# Foreach-loop with if (isset) doesn't work

Tags: php, foreach

I made a register.php-page and instead of writing:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
} else {
    $username = '';
}
```

multiple times (one for the username, birtday etc), I tried to store the (not-yet-set) variables/strings in a array:

```
$array = array('email', 'username', 'birth')
```

and then do a foreach-loop:

```
foreach ($array as $var) {
    if(isset($_POST['$var'])) {
    ${$var} = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['$var']);
    } else {
        ${$var} = '';
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, neiter if this is the right way to do it, (guessing the ${$var} is wrong). What's wrong and how should I fix it?:(

Comment: `isset($_POST['$var'])` is treat as a string, you need to use `isset($_POST["$var"]]`

Comment: Understand the difference between the string `'$var'` and the string within your `$var`

Comment: change '$var' to $var in $_POST and ${$var} to $$var. This may fix your problem. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable expansion does not occur through `'` literals -- either wrap the variable in double quotes OR skip the quotes entirely:

```
if(isset($_POST[$var])) {
//or
if(isset($_POST["$var"])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`isset($_POST['$var'])` should just be `isset($_POST[$var])`.

Comment: You're right. Strange usage though. Should maybe wrap the whole thing in a function, like `getPost($key)` that returns an empty string, or the value.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the '$var' thing, you should use an array to store the escaped input rather than declaring variables directly from input. By doing it the way you are doing it, you make it easy to accidentally introduce security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ''?

```
foreach ($array as $var) {
    if(isset($_POST[$var])) {
    $$var = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST[$var]);
    } else {
        $$var = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought I needed to, or that it didn't matter. Just learned PHP btw :)